# Two PWM signals from TL494

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, tl494

I need to generate two open-loop PWM signals with different duty cycles for my converter. The frequency is 20kHz. I did generate one signal.

- Should I use another TL494 and connect it to the same supply and ground to generate the second signal?
- Will the two signals be synchronized?

Comment: It's not guaranteed that two independent TL494s will have the exactly same switching frequencies with the same RT and CT values. So a second TL494 may not be syncronized to the other one. Some other controllers (from TI, ON etc) have a SYNC pin for syncronizing. Maybe you should try one of them.

Comment: Will shorting the RT and CT pins on the two TL494s be able to give synchronised values?

Comment: @Sparky256 How do I generate the PWM signals for the gates of my MOSFETs? Any IC you would recommend?

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog. We cannot recommend specific products on this site, but gee-whiz there must be a thousand PWM controller IC's to choose from. Think about what your goal is and work from there. Without a clear goal you are lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texas Instrument's application report [Designing Switching Voltage Regulators With the TL494](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva001e/slva001e.pdf) contains a section about synchronization, including multiple TL494's in a master/slave setup. See section **"4.2.1 Synchronization"**